# Flutter widget.snapshot.data vs snapshot.data

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm confused about `widget.snapshot.data["info"]` and `snapshot.data["info"].` Can anyone explain me this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

widget.snapshot.data["info"] should be used when a **StatefulWidget** is used and the **snapshot** is from the **StatefulWidget**

Example

```
class ViewDocuments extends StatefulWidget {
  DocumentSnapshot snapshot;

  ViewDocuments(this.snapshot);

  @override
  _ViewDocumentsState createState() => _ViewDocumentsState();
}

class _ViewDocumentsState extends State<ViewDocuments> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text("${widget.snapshot.data["info"]}"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Basically you use **widget.---** to access fields in a **StatefulWidget** class State, it is a way for a **StatefulWidget** and its **State** to communicate

For **snapshot.data["info"]**, it should be used in **StatelessWidget** since it doesn't have a **State**

For Example

```
class ViewDocuments extends StatelessWidget {
  DocumentSnapshot snapshot;

  ViewDocuments(this.snapshot);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text("${snapshot.data["info"]}"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I hope this helps you.